# ConstraintLayout views at top left when added programatically

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Although I saw some similar questions, non of the answers worked for me. Maybe I'm missing something simple, but I'm failing to see what it is.
I have a ConstraintLayout with an ImageView inside. I'm adding views dynamically & relative to the image view. All the views are stuck to the top left corner of the image view..

Here's the Container layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mapImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="matrix"
                android:src="@drawable/fullmap"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the code for adding those views:

```
Map<Integer, Point> positions = createPoints(levels);
ConstraintLayout mapLayout = findViewById(R.id.mapLayout);
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
for (int i = 0; i < levels.size(); i++) {
    ConstraintLayout levelItem = (ConstraintLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.quest_map_level_item, mapLayout, false);
    levelItem.setId(i);
    Point point = positions.get(i);
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(levelItem);
    mapLayout.addView(levelItem);
    constraintSet.connect(levelItem.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, R.id.mapLayout, ConstraintSet.START, point.x);
    constraintSet.connect(levelItem.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.mapLayout, ConstraintSet.TOP, point.y);
    constraintSet.applyTo(levelItem);
}
```

As I've mentioned above, the result is having all the views at the top left corner. To be clear - point.x & point.y are correct and are for sure not pointing to the top left corner.

Thanks a lot,
Giora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to constrain the newly added `Views` you should be cloning the `ConstraintSet` of the parent layout instead of the `View` that is being added. After defining constraints, this `ConstraintSet` should then be applied to the parent layout. Also make sure that new `View` is added to the layout before cloning the `ConstraintSet`.

In your case the added `View` is also a `ConstraintLayout` which is why you are not getting any errors when cloning the set.

These lines:

```
constraintSet.clone(levelItem);
constraintSet.applyTo(levelItem);
```

should be changed to:

```
constraintSet.clone(mapLayout);
constraintSet.applyTo(mapLayout);
```

Comment: Thank a lot! This did the trick... I would add to the answer that the addView must happen before the clone(). Thanks again.

Comment: Nice suggestion, I missed it! Updated the answer.